# javascript - read cookie value, trigger function if part of string =

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie -

LLBVAT

and the string in the cookie is (which can change, but the structure will remain the same):

So I know I'll need to read the cookie, and then run a function on the returned string.

```
A0A64A06500000B754E9DD10B1381:0:false:false:99:9999:99:false:0:-1:0:0:0:EMAILPCD:1319094000000:82
```

I need to trigger a function on the second false (4th value).

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Is it possible to use less code:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

split the value on `:`

```
var trigger = "A0A64A06500000B754E9DD10B1381:0:false:false:99:9999:99:false:0:-1:0:0:0:EMAILPCD:1319094000000:82".split(':')[3] === "false";
if (trigger) func();
```

the comparison is very important as `if ("false")` is truthy

---

Get a cookie from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

```
docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return null; }
    return unescape(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|.*;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*((?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?).*"), "$1"));
  },
  /**
  * docCookies.setItem(sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure)
  *
  * @argument sKey (String): the name of the cookie;
  * @argument sValue (String): the value of the cookie;
  * @optional argument vEnd (Number, String, Date Object or null): the max-age in seconds (e.g., 31536e3 for a year) or the
  *  expires date in GMTString format or in Date Object format; if not specified it will expire at the end of session; 
  * @optional argument sPath (String or null): e.g., "/", "/mydir"; if not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document location;
  * @optional argument sDomain (String or null): e.g., "example.com", ".example.com" (includes all subdomains) or "subdomain.example.com"; if not
  * specified, defaults to the host portion of the current document location;
  * @optional argument bSecure (Boolean or null): cookie will be transmitted only over secure protocol as https;
  * @return undefined;
  **/
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/.test(sKey)) { return; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (typeof vEnd) {
        case "number": sExpires = "; max-age=" + vEnd; break;
        case "string": sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd; break;
        case "object": if (vEnd.hasOwnProperty("toGMTString")) { sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toGMTString(); } break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=" + escape(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return; }
    var oExpDate = new Date();
    oExpDate.setDate(oExpDate.getDate() - 1);
    document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=; expires=" + oExpDate.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) { return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie); }
};

// docCookies.setItem("test1", "Hello world!");
// docCookies.setItem("test2", "Hello world!", new Date(2020, 5, 12));
// docCookies.setItem("test3", "Hello world!", new Date(2027, 2, 3), "/blog");
// docCookies.setItem("test4", "Hello world!", "Sun, 06 Nov 2022 21:43:15 GMT");
// docCookies.setItem("test5", "Hello world!", "Tue, 06 Dec 2022 13:11:07 GMT", "/home");
// docCookies.setItem("test6", "Hello world!", 150);
// docCookies.setItem("test7", "Hello world!", 245, "/content");
// docCookies.setItem("test8", "Hello world!", null, null, "example.com");
// docCookies.setItem("test9", "Hello world!", null, null, null, true);

// alert(docCookies.getItem("test1"));
```

So then:

```
if (docCookies.getItem("LLBVAT").split(':')[3] === "false") triggerFunction();
```

Comment: the string will change, so I will actually need to read the cookie

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
function getTheResult(){
  //you can get this value as parameter in this function
  var val="A0A64A06500000B754E9DD10B1381:0:false:false:99:9999:99:false:0:-1:0:0:0:EMAILPCD:1319094000000:82";    

  //this final result will be as below by splitting the string
  var theresult =val.split(':')[3];    

  return theresult; //this will return 'false'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either the [jQuery plugin or Plain Old Javascript for cookie management](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html). From there, as others have said, pass the result to a method that splits the string and calls another based on the condition.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var cookieValue = jQuery.cookie("LLBVAT");
    var result = process(cookieValue);
    if(result)
    { //do stuff }
});

function process(cookie){
   var result = cookie.split(':')[3];    
   return result === "false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Small update to the Mozilla developers code mentioned above: document.cookie returns only the cookies where the domain and the path match to the current URL (due to the security restrictions). To read cookies created for another path you can use the following workaround:

```
  getItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
if (!sKey) {
  return "";
 }
var allCookie;
if (!sDomain && !sPath) {
  allCookie = document.cookie;
} else {
  var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", (sDomain ? sDomain : "") + (sPath ? sPath : ""));
  document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
  allCookie = iframe.contentDocument.cookie;
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
  iframe = null;
}
var sValue = decodeURIComponent(allCookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
return sValue;
```

},